# CodeIgniter sessions versus PHP native session support

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I would like to know, why does CodeIgniter define its own session class
rather than make use of PHP's built-in _SEESION array and what are the
advanages of using one versus the other?

Thanks.

Comment: Refer to this page: [Codeigniter Session Class](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/sessions.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have been working with CodeIgniter for quite a while now and I have pondered this subject myself.  I think the main advantage of using CI Sessions rather than native PHP session is that CI Sessions offer a lot more security.

If you are hosting your website on shared hosting you have to be careful not to share your session data with the other hosts.  CI sessions will regenerate the session ID but native PHP sessions don't.

CI sessions also allow you to encrypt your session in the config file

```
$config['encryption_key'] = "YOUR KEY";
```